# UIActivityViewController issue with the Edit Actions title - SHARE_SHEET_EDIT_ACTIONS_BUTTON_TITLE

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, uiactivityviewcontroller

I'm facing an issue related to the `UIActivityViewController` with **Edit Actions** title.

It shows **`SHARE_SHEET_EDIT_ACTIONS_BUTTON_TITLE`** instead of **`Edit Actions..`**

**Findings:**

1. Working fine in the other apps such as WhatsApp and Instagram.
2. The same code is working fine in the newly created iOS apps.
3. Tested in iOS 15.0 and iOS 14.0+ using Xcode Version 13.1.
4. Tested on both Device and Simulators.

**Notes:**

The project is in ObjectiveC and created before 3 years.

**Code:**

```
NSString* shareText = @"Sharing an eddress with you";
NSURL *website = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://eddress.co/EDDRSS"];
NSArray *shareArray = @[shareText, website];
UIActivityViewController *activityVC = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:shareArray applicationActivities:nil];
[activityVC setValue:@"Someone shared an eddress with you" forKey:@"subject"];
NSArray *excludeActivities = @[UIActivityTypeAirDrop,
                                   UIActivityTypePrint,
                                   UIActivityTypeAssignToContact,
                                   UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll,
                                   UIActivityTypeAddToReadingList,
                                   UIActivityTypePostToFlickr,
                                   UIActivityTypePostToVimeo];
activityVC.excludedActivityTypes = excludeActivities;
[self presentViewController:activityVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

**Screenshots:**

[image]

[image]

Any help on this is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found the root cause and solution for this. All was happened due to the **Localization**

Below code is the real culprit

```
#pragma mark - Method Swizzling
- (NSString *)customLocaLizedStringForKey:(NSString *)key value:(NSString *)value table:(NSString *)tableName {
    NSBundle*bundle = [BundleLocalization sharedInstance].localizationBundle;
    return [bundle customLocaLizedStringForKey:key value:value table:tableName];
}
```

This returns `SHARE_SHEET_EDIT_ACTIONS_BUTTON_TITLE` instead of `Edit Actions..`

See the below Log

```
key:SHARE_SHEET_EDIT_ACTIONS_BUTTON_TITLE value: tableName:Localizable
return: SHARE_SHEET_EDIT_ACTIONS_BUTTON_TITLE
key:SHARE_SHEET_EDIT_SECTION_TITLE_FAVORITES value: tableName:Localizable
return: SHARE_SHEET_EDIT_SECTION_TITLE_FAVORITES
key:SHARE_SHEET_EDIT_ACTIONS_BUTTON_TITLE value: tableName:Localizable
return: SHARE_SHEET_EDIT_ACTIONS_BUTTON_TITLE
key:Copy[Activity] value:Copy tableName:Localizable
return: Copy
key:SHARE_SHEET_EDIT_ACTIONS_BUTTON_TITLE value: tableName:Localizable
return: SHARE_SHEET_EDIT_ACTIONS_BUTTON_TITLE
key:SHARE_SHEET_DEFAULTS_REMOVE_BUTTON_TITLE value: tableName:Localizable
return: SHARE_SHEET_DEFAULTS_REMOVE_BUTTON_TITLE
key:Copy[Activity] value:Copy tableName:Localizable
return: Copy
key:SHARE_SHEET_EDIT_SECTION_TITLE_OTHER value: tableName:Localizable
return: SHARE_SHEET_EDIT_SECTION_TITLE_OTHER
key:SHARE_SHEET_EDIT_ACTIONS_BUTTON_TITLE value: tableName:Localizable
return: SHARE_SHEET_EDIT_ACTIONS_BUTTON_TITLE
```

**Temporary Solution:**

```
#pragma mark - Method Swizzling

- (NSString *)customLocaLizedStringForKey:(NSString *)key value:(NSString *)value table:(NSString *)tableName {
    if ([key isEqualToString:@"SHARE_SHEET_EDIT_ACTIONS_BUTTON_TITLE"]) {
        return @"Edit Actions...";
    }
    else if ([key isEqualToString:@"SHARE_SHEET_EDIT_SECTION_TITLE_FAVORITES"]) {
        return @"Favorites";
    }
    else if ([key isEqualToString:@"SHARE_SHEET_EDIT_SECTION_TITLE_OTHER"]) {
        return @"Other Actions";
    }
    else if ([key isEqualToString:@"SHARE_SHEET_EDIT_SECTION_TITLE_SUGGESTIONS"]) {
        return @"Suggestions";
    }
    else if ([key isEqualToString:@"SHARE_SHEET_DEFAULTS_REMOVE_BUTTON_TITLE"]) {
        return @"Remove";
    }
    else {
        NSBundle *bundle = [BundleLocalization sharedInstance].localizationBundle;
        return [bundle customLocaLizedStringForKey:key value:value table:tableName];
    }
}
```